# How define the size and the location of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I want to develop a code which allows to display a counter.

The counter, which is in a JLabel (compte), itself in a JPanel (panneau) is displayed well but I can't define its size and position.

Here are the codes of the two classes of my program:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Compteur compteur = new Compteur();
        compteur.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

import javafx.scene.layout.Border;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Compteur extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private int cpt = 0;
    JButton boutonPlus = new JButton("+");
    JButton boutonMoins = new JButton("-");
    JPanel paneau = new JPanel();
    JLabel compte = new JLabel();


    public Compteur() {
        setSize(1700, 900);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        boutonMoins.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 30);
        boutonPlus.setBounds(250, 100, 100, 30);
        LineBorder lineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        compte.setBorder(lineBorder);
        this.add(boutonMoins);
        this.add(boutonPlus);
        paneau.add(compte);
        this.add(paneau);
        AfficherCompteur();
        boutonMoins.addActionListener(this);
        boutonPlus.addActionListener(this);
        this.pack();
    }

    private void AfficherCompteur() {
        compte.setText(String.valueOf(cpt));

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == boutonMoins) {
            try {
                cpt--;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource()==boutonPlus) {
            try {
                cpt++;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        AfficherCompteur();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing uses a layout manager by default to arrange components. If you wish to provide absolute positioning you must first disable the default layout manager. This can be achieved by the following.

```
public Compteur() {
    setLayout(null);
```

However I would recommend against absolute layouts, these are generally hard to work with and difficult to maintain. Consider reading up on layout managers in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a Component to have an absolute position on a JFrame the JFrame must have an internal layout of **null** (to my knowledge).